# MatToolBar delete left and right spaces

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hello I want to delete the space in the toolbar between my menu icon and the screen corner

I tryed using this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-toolbar {
    margin-left: -1.25em;
}
```

And it works, deleted the left space perfectly but also move the whole bar leaving a white space in the right side

Basically I want to remove those spaces:

[image]

Its any way to doit ? im pretty new with angular material and css.

Comment: Just remove the padding of  `.mat-toolbar-single-row` class

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks

Comment: If you give a bit wide explanation as answer ill click as correct

Comment: I have added a bit explanation as answer. Let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know every angular material UI component has their own `html` and `css` by default. So if you go to the official github file of `mat-toolbar` component, you could see that there is a css `class` named `mat-toolbar-single-row` which actually gets applied to our custom `mat-toolbar` element(when rendered on browser). This `mat-toolbar-single-row` has a padding of `16px`. That's why you are getting the extra space in the toolbar between your menu icon and the screen corner. Adding github link of the `scss` file of `mat-toolbar` https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/toolbar/toolbar.scss for your reference. Hope that resolves your query